# Lexical this in consice methods in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, this

Below is my code with explanation.
I have a class with its member functions and variables as below. functionOne & functionTwo are concise methods.

```
function MyUtils() {
    this.actions = {
        functionOne(param1, param2) {
            console.log('This is first function which is not in action');
        },
        functionTwo(param1, param2) {
            console.log('This is second function calling function three');
            //HOW DO I CALL functionThree HERE?
            // I tried doing - this.functionThree() but not working
        }
    }

    this.functionThree() {
        console.log('This is third function');
    }
}
```

If the function two is called then I want function three to be callen in it?

Comment: You have syntax errors in your example. Please fix those first. =)

Comment: You can store the outer context `this` in the first line of `MyUtils`, example: `var self = this;`, then you can safely use: `self.actions`, `self.functionThree`, and so on.

Comment: How are you instantiating `MyUtils`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it without this keyword, this uses closure syntax in javascript:

```
function MyUtils() {

    function functionThree() {
        console.log('This is third function');
    }

    this.actions = {
        functionOne(param1, param2) {
            console.log('This is first function which is not in action');
        },
        functionTwo(param1, param2) {
            console.log('This is second function calling function three');
            //HOW DO I CALL functionThree HERE?
            // I tried doing - this.functionThree() but not working
            functionThree();

        }
    }


}
```

and here is the output from the repl: (found [here](https://repl.it/IvU4))

```
clear
Native Browser JavaScript

This is second function calling function three
This is third function
=> undefined
```

Comment: Why use repl when a built-in stack snippet would do?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function MyUtils() {
  var that = this;

  this.actions = {
    functionOne(param1, param2) {
        console.log('This is first function which is not in action');
    },
    functionTwo(param1, param2) {
        console.log('This is second function calling function three');
        that.functionThree();
    }
  }

  this.functionThree = function functionThree() {
    console.log('This is third function');
  }
}
```

To check if it works:

```
var utils = new MyUtils();
utils.actions.functionTwo();

// Will output:
// This is second function calling function three
// This is third function
```